# How to create asp:table when click on add button

Tags: vb.net

How to genera dynamic table it constant asp:textbox and sum other controls, when click on button in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function changeLink()
    {
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML="<table style='width: 100%'><tr><td>              <input type='Text'/></td></tr></table>";

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="myAnchor">

    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeLink()" value="Change link">

    </body>
    </html>
```